# How to make a custom control compatible with errorProvider?

Tags: winforms

I have a winform custom control that looks like :

```
Public Class MyCustomControl
    Inherits Control
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged    

    'Some textboxes...
    private Textbox1 as textbox
    private Textbox2 as textbox
    private Textbox3 as textbox

    'Control value
    Property Value as MyCustomClass
        get
            'Extract some values from textboxes and return MyCustomClass (a separate custom object)
        end get
        Set(value As MyCustomClass)
            'Set the values of the textboxes from the Value object
        end Set
    end Property
end class
```

I would like to insert this object in a winform and I would like my control to be "compatible" with errorProvider. Such that if I insert an errorProvider in the form and I call : errorProvider.SetError(MyCustomControl, "Error message"), it will show the error message on a specific text box in my custom control according to a custom logic.

Does anyone know which interface should be implemented or how to that please ?

Thanks. Cheers,

Comment: You don't need to implement any interface, ErrorProvider will attach to any control on the Form.

Comment: Yes but how it will know where to show the error icon ? In this case for example, (a control with 3 textboxes) where this will be shown ? I made some tests and it's not shown anywhere.

Comment: You will use SetIconAlignment and SetIconPadding to control where the error provider notification is displayed relative to the control

Comment: I think you didn't get the question :) ! When you call errorProvider.SetError on a Textbox, the error icon is shown somewhere by default. How do you that on a custom control such that it will show the error icon on a specific textbox. It's not about Icon alignement nor padding.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible because the Error Provider knows nothing about the TextBoxes inside your custom control. It only sees the custom control boundary (Left/Top/Width/Height). All you can do is adjust the icon padding to get it close to your internal TextBox as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do would be better achieved with a `UserControl`, instead of inheriting directly from `Control`. (Having three `TextBox` instances inside your control is a good indication here.) In your `UserControl` you have a couple of options:

1. Add an `ErrorProvider` component and hook it up to each `TextBox`; or
2. For each `TextBox` expose it by making it `public` or via a public property, and then in your form hook it up to the form's `ErrorProvider`.

Ideally, you would use a `BindingSource` and data bind each `TextBox`, with the `ErrorProvider.DataSource` being set to your `BindingSource`.